# How do Traditional Latin Mass going Catholics usually prepare and receive their sacraments of initiation?

Tags: catholicism, sacraments

Our parish is starting to off a Traditional Latin Mass and there's a group in our diocese that has their children confirmed in the that form as well.  It's quite a bit different, we were wanting to do this for our kids, but we found out about it way too late.  But I'm wondering, what are the ages and what kind of preparation do Traditional Catholics do for the Sacraments of Baptism, Confirmation and their First Communion?  What ages are appropriate for receiving these sacraments?  Is First Communion generally withheld until after Confirmation?

Answer (score 1):

The ages rarely differ from the general practice in that region. As far as preparation goes, the particular pedagogy might vary (e.g expectations may be higher), but it's not substantially different, certainly not in any uniform way.

Some parishes that host both forms of the rites use a common sacramental preparation program (Especially for converts), some have them separate.

> Is First Communion generally withheld until after Confirmation?

That would be up to the diocese and not dependent on the form of the Liturgy. The reason why some places do Confirmation before 1st Communion is a desire to restore the traditional ordering, but that ordering was displaced not with Post Vatican II reforms but with Pius X's lowering of the age of First Communion to 7.

Answer (score 1):

**How do Traditional Latin Mass going Catholics usually prepare and receive their sacraments of initiation?**

The neighbouring parish to where I live has a priest who Mass in both Rites. Each liturgical form has its’ own way of dealing with liturgical matters.

Children who attend the Extraordinary Form of the Mass, have catechetical classes using the the now famous Baltimore Catechism, whereas the other children use whatever has been approved by the archdiocese.

As for the age requirements and barring any local decisions by local ordinaries, the ages of reception of the sacraments are the same in both Rites.

Children are generally able to to make their first confession and then [first communion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Communion) at about the age of seven (7) which it generally took as being the age of reason.

Children may be also be confirmed at the age of seven in either Rite. However, practice will depend on the disposition and practices of the local churches. Here in Vancouver, the age of reception for the sacrament of confirmation is about twelve or thirteen (12 or 13). I have known of one diocese delaying this sacrament until adulthood. But that particular practice is far from the norm.

> Even where a later age has been set, a bishop may not refuse to confer the sacrament on younger children who request it, provided they are baptized, have the use of reason, are suitably instructed and are properly disposed and able to renew the baptismal promises (letter of the Congregation for Divine Worship and the Discipline of the Sacraments published in its 1999 bulletin, pages 537–540). [Confirmation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation)